# NetworkManager won't start after upgrades

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I'm having trouble getting NetworkManager to start after upgrading.

I initially tried running: `sudo service network-manager restart` to see if that would kick it again, but I get the following error:

```
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So I checked `systemctl` and `jounalctl`. systemctl returns the following:

```
 NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-06-05 12:25:53 CDT; 1min 7s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 4097 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 4097 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

and journalctl gives me the following:

```
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3727 and the job result is failed.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit NetworkManager.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3808 and the job result is done.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 05 12:25:53 joule systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3808 and the job result is failed.
Jun 05 12:25:55 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-10ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:25:55 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-24ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:26:19 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce: scheduled expiry is in the past (-1ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:26:19 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-14ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:27:00 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:27:05 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-10ms), your system is too slow
Jun 05 12:27:15 joule systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
-- Subject: A start job for unit motd-news.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit motd-news.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3889.
Jun 05 12:27:15 joule systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit motd-news.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jun 05 12:27:15 joule systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
-- Subject: A start job for unit motd-news.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit motd-news.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3889.
Jun 05 12:28:20 joule /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2021]: (EE) client bug: timer event6 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-10ms), your system is too slow
```

One lead I have is that my ethernet interface is named `enp0s31f6` so if I run `sudo dhclient enp0s31f6` I can reconnect to the internet. However, I would like to use this machine as a server so that's not a super sustainable option.

I tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and adding the following but it didn't seem to help.

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

I'm pretty stuck and would be curious to know what people would try next?

**Metadata:**

```
> dhclient --version 
isc-dhclient-4.4.1
> hostnamectl
...
           Boot ID: 0789175e8bad4cb58f441217f4d1135d
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-113-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Sounds like a serious bug, maybe you could post a bug report as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu